# React: Can't access object properties from rest API in render function

Tags: json, mongodb, rest, reactjs, undefined

I'm new here so sorry if I'm breaking any rules.
I've looked pretty thoroughly through the forums and haven't been able to find an answer to my issue.

I've been following a rest API tutorial on youtube with a react frontend. I've replicated the code almost identically after running into this issue but my error still persists.

I'm trying to render a list of all the employees that match a name in a search.

I've logged the data to console and I know I'm getting the correct Json data. However, when I try to display it (as you can see in the span) I get:

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined"

Everywhere I've looked it suggests the issue stems from the initial state being undefined, but I think I've covered that with "getInitialState" correct?

Also, If I don't try to use any properties it produces the correct length in lists, it's just that the rows are empty. I.E. if I search for 3 things the list is 3 rows. 4 things, the list is 4 rows. I just can't seem to display their properties.

The only other thing I can think of is that I'm forcing my mongodb to run in sudo to avoid changing ownership, but I doubt that has anything to do with it?

Here's the data I'm trying to fetch (an array of employee json sets):

```
[
    {
        "_id": "598e2c934bf28a7106043bd5",
        "fullname": "Michael Trinco",
        "__v": 0,
        "action3": false,
        "action2": false,
        "action1": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "598e2c9b4bf28a7106043bd6",
        "fullname": "Andrew Holdaway",
        "__v": 0,
        "action3": false,
        "action2": false,
        "action1": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "598e4d10a29532714f857f33",
        "fullname": "David Holdaway",
        "__v": 0,
        "action3": false,
        "action2": false,
        "action1": true
    }
]
```

Code:

```
<script type="text/babel">


var Employees = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return({
            employees: []
        });
    },
    render:function(){
        var employees = this.state.employees;
        console.log(employees);
        employees = employees.map(function(employee, index){
            return(
                <li key={index}>
                    <span>{employee.obj.fullname}</span>
                </li>
            );
        });
        return(
            <div id="employee-container">
                <form id="search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Search by fullname:</label>
                    <input type="text" ref="fullname" placeholder="Search by Name..." />
                    <input type="submit" value="Find Employees" />
                </form>
                <ul>{employees}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fullname = this.refs.fullname.value;

        fetch('/api/employees?fullname='+fullname).then(function(data){
            return data.json();
        }).then(json => 
            {this.setState({employees: json});
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Employees />, document.getElementById('output'));

</script>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Which version of react are you using. ```react.createClass``` has been deprecated. Also, you're trying to render state that hasn't been set yet. Also, you need to stringify your json in order to display an object in the render method. Set your employee state in the ```componentWillMount``` lifecycle method and then {JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)} in order to display the object in your render method. If no one has given you a full answer by tomorrow i'll write you up a working example in the morn. I'm off to bed now. =)

Comment: script react@15. is it deprecated in this version?

what do you mean by render a state that hasn't been set? (Sorry i'm so new to react)

I honestly don't understand much but hopefully by your morning I can wrap my head around everything you've said. 

Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated example. This should get you going. I need to do an adjustment but it's way past my bedtime. I'll hit this again in the morn. Right now you have to type the persons name exactly and we need it to match no matter how many characters match in the name. I don't know why this has been such a pain to accomplish. It's a good learning experience though!

```js
console.clear()
const MOCK_DATA = [
    {
        "_id": "598e2c934bf28a7106043bd5",
        "fullname": "Michael Trinco",
        "__v": 0,
        "action3": false,
        "action2": false,
        "action1": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "598e2c9b4bf28a7106043bd6",
        "fullname": "Andrew Holdaway",
        "__v": 0,
        "action3": false,
        "action2": false,
        "action1": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "598e4d10a29532714f857f33",
        "fullname": "David Holdaway",
        "__v": 0,
        "action3": false,
        "action2": false,
        "action1": true
    }
]
  

class Employees extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      filterText: '',
      filteredNames: ''
    }
    this.filterUpdate = this.filterUpdate.bind(this)
    this.search = this.search.bind(this)
  }
  filterUpdate(e) {
    this.setState({filterText: e.target.value})
  }
  search() {
    console.log("search triggered: ", this.state.filterText)
    const input = this.state.filterText.toLowerCase()
    const names = MOCK_DATA.filter(person => {
      return person.fullname.toLowerCase().indexOf(input)
    })
    this.setState({filteredNames: names})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="employee-container">
          <label>Search by Fullname:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.filterText}
            onChange={this.filterUpdate}
            placeholder="Search by Name..."
          />
          <button onClick={this.search}>Search</button>
          <div>
          <pre>
          <code>
            {JSON.stringify(this.state.filteredNames, null, 2)}
          </code>
          </pre>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Employees />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #212121;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.employee-container {
  margin: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input, button {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of your mongo data? maybe console.log your fetch json?

Comment: I have updated the question with the data I'm looking to grab :)

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help!
Since i'm trying to fetch this data off of a rest API I assume I'd need a fetch someone in there once i remove the const data set correct?

Comment: Assuming the fetch statement is meant to be similar to what you showed me before?

Also the search is returning JSON for objects i DONT search for while the others are shown. Have I misunderstood something?

Thanks for your time again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah! No sweat bret! I forgot to put back the mapped display component for your names. I only showed the json to troubleshoot. There is a bug I need to fix and i'll add your fetch example back in there. cheers mate!